# Encoding problems with Zend Lucene

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, zend-lucene

I have some problems with Zend_Lucene, especially with characters encoding.

Because I'm french, I have to store a lot of specials characters...

So I set up a zend_lucene engine, and try to store my text.

Unfortunately, the text are stored with bad characters, as if Zend_Lucene could not read those characters (I've opened the cfs file to be sure about it).

But I set the default encoding as UTF-8, my input are in UTF-8...

The idea I got, was because I use windows and the file created by Zend_Lucene is not in UTF-8. But I have no idea how to create an UTF-8, or to make this up.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended using Mysql Full Search, as my project was not that big.